# Superiority of hyperledger over Ethereum

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum

I am trying to build a block chain system. How could i find the best platform ? Is there any Superiority for the Hyper-ledger over ethereum ?

Comment: Without being an expert I don't think Stackoverflow is the correct site for this question. Perhaps https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ or https://eosio.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ethereum and Hyperledger Fabric are suited for very different visions in regard with their fields of application.

Hyperledger Fabric provides customisable and extendable architecture that may be used in diverse fields ranging from banking to supply chain to healthcare et al. Ethereum’s unique feature of providing us with a cross-disciplinary platform for all kinds of transactions and use cases.

1. ethereum is permissionless and Hyperledger Fabric is permissioned.
2. consesus mechanism used by Ethereum use Proof of Work (POW), Hyperledger Fabric use Byzantine Fault Tolerant(BFT).

**Issue with POW**

```
- It requires lot of computational power (CPU cycles, GPU, electricity)
```

to get random bits.

```
- Tragedy of the commons  Miners reward reduces over time, when this occurs less miners will mine these blocks. This could open up window for malicious users who can easily acquire more than 51% of network and thus destroying the network.
```

3. Following are the languages in which smart contracts are written for ethereum and hyper-ledger

   - ethereum :solidity,LLL,serpent
   - hyper-ledger :go or java
4. crypto currency

   - Ethereum :Another noteworthy difference is that Ethereum features a
     built-in cryptocurrency called Ether. It is used to pay rewards to
     nodes that contribute to reach consensus by mining blocks as well as
     to pay transaction fees.
   - Hyperledger : Hyperledger Fabric does not require a build-in cryptocurrency as consensus is not reached via mining. With Fabric, however, it is possible to develop a native currency or a digital token with chaincode.